# Remove selection around QPushButton text

Tags: css, qt, button, stylesheet

When i add QPushButton on my form, i get this:

[image]

You can see ugly text selection (into the button). How can i remove it?
Here is my CSS of this button:

```
    enterButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { \
                                    padding: 6px; \
                                    background: #369; \
                                    color: white; \
                                    font-size: 13px;\
                                    border: 0; \
                                    border-radius: 3px; \
                                }\
                                QPushButton:hover { \
                                    background: #47a; \
                                }\
                                QPushButton:pressed { \
                                    background: #58b; \
                                }");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have `Ubuntu` installed right now but I think `outline: 0px` should work:

```
enterButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { \
                                padding: 6px; \
                                background: #369; \
                                color: white; \
                                font-size: 13px;\
                                border: 0; \
                                border-radius: 3px; \
                                outline: 0px; \
                            }\
                            QPushButton:hover { \
                                background: #47a; \
                            }\
                            QPushButton:pressed { \
                                background: #58b; \
                            }");
```

Try it and come back with a feedback.

Comment: QPushButton:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    } says http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27656-Can-I-remove-hide-the-border-when-QPushButton-is-highlighted-focus-active